# PapaParse Chunk loads all the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, large-data, papaparse

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I'm using Papaparse to parse a huge CSV file to get the data set and plug into d3 and crossfiltering. FIRST, I used node.js just to run a server for ejs (I have not used any embedded js). When I run my application, it works like a charm. I see in the chunk function its getting results base on 10 mb default and i got data set. THEN I need to transfer my code to eclipse and convert it to jsp or html and run my websphere server instead of Node.js. When I run my application, I noticed the chunk is receiving ALL my dataset in one instead of doing 10MB per dataset and thats crashing my IE11 browser. Is this a bug? i tried to state the Papa.LocalChunkSize to equal amount of MB but it still loading all my dataset. Please i need help....

Here is my code just in case.

```
    var chunk1Finish = false;
var chunkMainData1Finish = false;
var finishLoadingMainData = false;

var mdata = [];

     Papa.parse("data2/week201751custinqfinal_v4.csv", {
     download: true,
     header: true,
     skipEmptyLines: true,
     complete: function() {
        console.log("complete!! the MAIN data length is: " + mdata.length);
        finishLoadingMainData = true;
        buildPage(finishLoadingMainData, finishLoadingTrendData);
     },
    chunk: function(results) {
        //mdata.push(results.data[0]);
        if(chunkMainData1Finish) {
            console.log("chunkMainData1Finish is true");
            Array.prototype.push.apply(mdata, results.data);
        } else {
            console.log("chunkMainData1Finish is false");
            mdata = results.data;
            chunkMainData1Finish = true;
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log("error!!!! " + error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`Papa.LocalChunkSize` wasn't working for me either. I added a `chunkSize` param to the `Papa.parse` function (just add it right before `chunk:` in your code).

Example : `chunk: 1024 * 1024 * 1,` is 1MB chunking.

Comment: not working now...
``Overload 1 of 2, '(input: string | ReadableStream | File, config?: ParseConfig<unknown> | undefined): ParseResult<unknown>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ worker: true; chunkSize: number; skipEmptyLines: true; header: true; chunk: (chunk: any) => void; error: (error: ParseError) => void; complete: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ParseConfig<unknown>'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'chunkSize' does not exist in type 'ParseConfig<unknown>'.``